# How do I enable LAME support for ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, lame

This isn't a duplicate. I am Debian 6 Squeeze and installed ffmpeg using apt-get. I didn't compile it from source. Later I installed lame from http://www.rarewares.org/. But when I try to use `ffmpeg -i some.flv -acodec lame -ab 128k my.mp3` I see error `Unknown encoder 'lame'`. If I try to use libmp3lame instead of lame the error says `Unknown encoder 'libmp3lame'`. But lame is installed. Any clue?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you didn't get `lame` from the Debian multimedia repos?

Comment: AFAIK, lame is not part of **official** Debian repos. Please correct me if I am wrong and point me to the package.

Comment: Debian do have issues with the patent encumbered nature of mp3 sure, but you can install it from the 'non-free' Squeeze repository. Details are [here](http://wiki.debian.org/MultimediaCodecs). I'm not sure if that's something you want to do for political or other reasons however.

Comment: @boehj, thanks for the link. Worked for me. Post your solution as an answer.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debian "support[s] ... and provide[s] infrastructure for non-free packages'. `lame` is such a package and is available in a 'non-free' repository. An explanation of how to access and configure this repository is available [here](http://wiki.debian.org/MultimediaCodecs).

The [Debian Social Contract](http://www.debian.org/social_contract) provides information on where 'non-free' software sits in the Debian software ecosystem.

Answer (score 3):

No need to install from source... The `ffmpeg` package that comes from `deb-multimedia.org` (`5:0.7.13-dmo2` ATM) has `libmp3lame` support.

I did the following on Squeeze (as root):

```
apt-get install deb-multimedia-keyring
```

Add to `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://www.deb-multimedia.org squeeze main non-free
```

then

```
apt-get update
```

then if you check it with `sudo apt-cache policy ffmpeg`, it should show that `ffmpeg` will come from `deb-multimedia.org`, not from the default repo. So:

```
apt-get install ffmpeg
```

and it should include LAME support. (I also had `lame` installed... I'm not sure if that's required though.)

Comment: Which version of FFmpeg does that give you? Just curious because the packaged versions are often quite outdated.

Comment: ffmpeg 5:0.7.13-dmo2, as I said.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe your ffmpeg wasn't installed with LAME support. I'd just say you download it from source and compile it with `--enable-libmp3lame`, or to be precise:

```
$ ./configure --enable-gpl --enable-liba52 --enable-libgsm --enable-libxvid \
--enable-libamr_nb --enable-libamr_wb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libogg \
--enable-libvorbis --enable-libfaac --enable-libfaad --enable-shared
```

It should then use your `lame` installation. If it can't: Get LAME [from here](http://lame.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Thanks slhck, I would rather try to find a fix which doesn't want me to compile source.

Answer (score 1):

Since July 2011, `lame` package is available in Debian main, see this page for the details:
http://packages.qa.debian.org/l/lame.html.

Please note that deb-multimedia package repository referred to in other answers here isn't supported, and is not recommended by Debian. In fact, it's not affiliated with Debian at all. More information can be found at this wiki page: http://wiki.debian.org/MultimediaCodecs

Answer (score 1):

Found in [this](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20quickly%20compile%20FFmpeg%20with%20mp3,%20aac%2B%20and%20x264) quick tutorial.

```
# cd /my/path/where/i/keep/compiled/stuff
# git clone git://source.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.git
# cd ffmpeg
# ./configure --enable-gpl --enable-libx264 --enable-libmp3lame --enable-nonfree --enable-libaacplus
# make
# make install
```

make sure you have all the dependencies installed, if you don't. check [this tutorial](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu) on how to install them

Answer (score 0):

When you use ffmpeg, it'll have a header like:

```
FFmpeg version 0.6.6-4:0.6.6-0ubuntu0.11.04.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2010 the Libav
 developers
  built on Jun 12 2012 16:35:16 with gcc 4.5.2
  configuration: --extra-version=4:0.6.6-0ubuntu0.11.04.1 --prefix=/usr --enable
-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-vdpau --enable-bzlib --enable-libgsm -
-enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis 
--enable-pthreads --enable-zlib --enable-libvpx --disable-stripping --enable-run
time-cpudetect --enable-vaapi --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --
enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-shared --disable-static
  libavutil     50.15. 1 / 50.15. 1
  libavcodec    52.72. 2 / 52.72. 2
  libavformat   52.64. 2 / 52.64. 2
  libavdevice   52. 2. 0 / 52. 2. 0
  libavfilter    1.19. 0 /  1.19. 0
  libswscale     0.11. 0 /  0.11. 0
  libpostproc   51. 2. 0 / 51. 2. 0
```

If, when you use ffmpeg, the configuration doesn't include `--enable-libmp3lame`, it wasn't compiled with LAME support, and there's no way to get it to use LAME.  By default, Debian and its derivatives do not provide an ffmpeg package with LAME support.  Unless you can find a package somewhere other than the official repositories, you'll have to compile it from source.